# Save PDF file to sub folder based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba, insert

I was having an issue for saving my worksheet as PDF to a folder based on a cell value "M5" + current month text in Arabic language like that (LS WF 28L مارس) and someone here helped me with a simple code and it works perfectly.

And now I want this PDF file to go to a sub folder inside my main folder ("D:\NEWGIZA") based on cell value "M7" as follows:

[image]

```vb
Sub ExportToPDF()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim Filename As String: Filename = "D:\NEWGIZA\" & ws.Range("M5").Value _
        & " " & Application.Text(Month(Date), "[$-401]mmmm") & ".pdf"
 
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Filename, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to use the `Date` instead `Month(Date)`, see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39946290/17172829)

Comment: I think you didnt get what I need

Comment: You right, i misunderstood your question. So the value of M7 is a number 1 to 8?

Comment: @Shrotter - yes right but the cell has formula if this will help.. I mean M7 has a formula to get this number 1:8 from another cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy to Different Subfolders

```vb
Sub ExportToPDF()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim sName As String
    
    Select Case ws.Range("M7").Value
        Case 1: sName = "NH1 (District One)"
        Case 2: sName = "NH2 (Carnell Park)"
        Case 3: sName = "NH3 (Ivory Hills)" 
        Case 4: sName = "NH4 (Westridge)" 
        Case 5: sName = "NH5 (Gold Cliff)" 
        Case 6: sName = "NH6 (Kingsrange)" 
        Case 7: sName = "NH7 (Amberville)" 
        Case 8: sName = "NH8 (Kingsrange PH2)"
        Case Else:
            MsgBox "Enter a number from 1 to 8 in cell 'M7'!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    Dim FilePath As String:
    FilePath = "D:\NEWGIZA\" & sName & "\" & ws.Range("M5").Value & " " _
        & Application.Text(Date, "[$-401]mmmm") & ".pdf"
 
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FilePath, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, so I think I have to change "subfolder in each line to my folder path for each one- right?

Comment: Just the subfolder name, of course. Next time share a list of them. Nobody wants to write them from scratch.

Comment: Actually i did that but the site considered it as a code and still giving me error to post it so I had to mke it as screenshot - however now i changed path but giving me runtime error -214724773 (8007007b) Document not saved .......and it seems that error in the last down part of the code

Comment: Check the file name (path) with `MsgBox Filename` to see if it is correct. If you have put the paths in the Select statement, remove  `"D:\NEWGIZA\" &` from the `FileName =` line.

Comment: everything is correct even I removed the formula in M7 and inserted the number manually but still the same error

Comment: Are you sure that the subfolders exist?

Comment: yes for sure with correct path like this for example ("D:\NEWGIZA\NH1 (District One)"

Comment: Error in debug appears in that part ( ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Filename, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Comment: Any new help or suggestions??

Comment: Haven't you refreshed the page? I've used your suggestion to edit the answer. It should work now (if the subfolders exist).

Comment: -just please one small problem - the month name text is not the current month it gives me (Jan not March) - before edit was correct

Comment: Sorry, replace `Month(Date)` with `Date`. Fixed.

Comment: like that?    FilePath = "D:\NEWGIZA\" & sName & "\" & ws.Range("M5").Value & " " _
        & Application.Text(Date. Fixed. "[$-401]mmmm") & ".pdf"

Comment: No, just `Date`.

Comment: yes ok done and it works now (March)

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. VBasic2008 - case solved